# Counting files in Zip - java nio 2

Tags: java, nio2

How to count number files in an existing archive with java nio 2, without iterate.
is a property like length() or size() exists ?
Like :

```
try (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("my.zip")) {
    size = zip.size();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You ask for NIO 2 *(added in Java 7)*, so why do you use the age-old IO (not NIO or NIO 2) class [`java.util.zip.ZipFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html)?

Comment: It's just an example, i want the equivalent to get size of archive with nio 2